# set datepicker date to the last available Saturday

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a requirement where I have to select only 'Saturday' from the datepicker, which I have done. The other requirement is that the default datepicker value should be set to last available Saturday of the present month or ealier one. So for e.g. if I click on the datepicker today i.e. 7th March, the datepicker should be set or shown as 4th March (which was the last available Saturday). This fix can be in jquery or c# code, anything is preferable, though its better I can try out both to see what works.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, just putting my code so others facing similar issues can you use. Following is my code logic.

```
$("#InputDate").datepicker('setDate', get_first_saturday(new Date));
    function get_first_saturday(d) {            
        var day = d.getDay();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = -(day + 1);
        firstsaturday = d.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd;
        return new Date(d.setDate(firstsaturday));
    }
```

Thanks.